# jquery append() not working

Tags: jquery

I have this really simple fiddle set up, if someone could point out why it's not working I'd really appreciate it, been struggling to figure this out for some time now.

Here's the code:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        alert('This thing works.');
        $(this).append('<input type="file" name="test">');
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

[Also, Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9xwDj/)

Comment: You can't append any thing to input element.

Comment: What is the exact expected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't append anything to an `input`, use `.after` or `.replaceWith`. The input is an element that may not contain child elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't append anything to `input` element

Answer (score 1):

use `.after()` or `.before()` or `.inserAfter()`:

```
$(this).after('<input type="file" name="test">');
```